# How to change height of class in edit mode

Tags: page-layout

i am trying to change the style of my css class in edit mode but nothing happens here is my code

```
        <Publishing:EditModePanel runat="server" id="editmodestyles">

        <script type="text/javascript">$(.center).css('height', '300px');</script>

            <SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/Core Styles/editmode15.css %&gt;" After="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/Core Styles/pagelayouts15.css %&gt;" runat="server">
            </SharePoint:CssRegistration>

        </Publishing:EditModePanel>
```

Comment: Might be missing [`document ready`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)? Anyway, why use JS when you could just add CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be some small details missing that's the cause. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
        $('.center').css('height', '300px');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i cant save when adding that code

Comment: @Martin You can't save? Ok, I have never experienced that before when adding custom javascript to the pages.

Comment: Yes i cant save. The ribbon inside Edit also gets disabled

Comment: I will update my code